# How to display a Spark dataframe using Quick watch in Visual Studio while using xunit?

Tags: c#, apache-spark, xunit

If I set a debugger and type`df.Show()` in Quick Watch, the dataframe is printed in the console. Since xunit does not support Console ouput, when I do the same while debugging the test case, dataframe is not displayed. Any suggestion on how to do this?